# LinqToSql Sub Entiity Multiple And Operators

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

Hi I have an Array of Featureset Id , My Vehicles table has got sub table as FeatureSets 
I wrote Sql Query Like

```
    SELECT [t0].[ID] 
FROM [dbo].[SearchResultView] AS [t0]
 Join [dbo].[VehicleFeatureSet] AS [t1] on t0.ID = t1.VehicleID
where t1.FeatureSetID = 1 and t1.FeatureSetID= 2 and t1.FeatureSetID= 3
```

I tried. But I Couldn't

```
var features = Request.QueryString["FeatureSets"].Split(',').ToList().ConvertAll(new Converter<string, int>(StrinToint)); 
IQueryable<SearchResultView> result = db.SearchResultViews.Where(m => m.Active == true);


            foreach (var featuree in features)
            {
                result = result.Where(m => m.VehicleFeatureSets.Any(c => c.FeatureSetID == featuree));
            }
```

How Can I write this LINQ Query

Comment: As pointed out by Mattytommo your SQL query contains a predicate that is always false (`t1.FeatureSetID = 1 and ...`). The funny thing is, I think your linq does exactly what you want to achieve, but of course the produced SQL is different. I think it contains `EXISTS`s, but it is supposed to contain them. This under the assumption that you want `SearchResultView` records that have _both_ 1 _and_ 2 _and_ 3 in their `VehicleFeatureSet`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I converted My LInq Query To Sql Query.
Actually, I couldn't write LINQ Query for this :)

```
 SELECT  Vehicle.[ID]
      ,[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Km]
      ,[RegistrationYear]
      ,[Price]
      ,[Currency]
      ,[AdsStartDate]
      ,[ThumbPhoto]
  FROM [SearchResultView] as Vehicle 
 left Join VehicleFeatureSet vs on Vehicle.ID=vs.VehicleID where Vehicle.Active = 1
 AND vs.FeatureSetID IN( 1,5,7,9)  //  1,5,7,9 comes from array
group by Vehicle.[ID],[Make]
      ,[Model]
      ,[Km]
      ,[RegistrationYear]
      ,[Price]
      ,[Currency]
      ,[AdsStartDate]
      ,[ThumbPhoto]
Having Count(vs.FeatureSetID) = 4 // length of my feature array
// sb = msSql query ,StringBuilder
// Then I used DataContext.ExecuteQuery()
db.ExecuteQuery<SearchResultView>(sb.ToString());
```

Problem fixed thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this? Although you're trying to match on the FeatureSetId being 1, 2 AND 3? I kept it as is, but they can be changed to an OR (||) instead if that's what you meant?

```
 var results = (from r in db.SearchResultViews
              join v in db.VehicleFeatureSet 
                 on r.ID equals v.VehicleID
              where r.Active 
                  && v.FeatureSetID == 1
                  && v.FeatureSetID == 2 
                  && v.FeatureSetID == 3
              select r.ID)
               .ToList();
```

**Edit: Okay, what I've now done is simply rewritten your foreach statement, you can replace it with the following:**

```
results = features
    .Aggregate(results, (current, feature) => current
        .Where(v => v.VehicleFeatureSets
            .Any(vf => vf.VehicleFeatureSetId == feature))
        .ToList());
```

Comment: Hi Thank for answer but I cant Write this query. I have array of FeatureSetID .  There are dynamic values.

Comment: Ah okay, check my edit that uses the VehicleFeatureSets property on the vehicle and uses the features list that was defined in your code. Hope that helps

Comment: Hi @mattytommo thanks for help. I got error. "Local sequence cannot be used in LINQ to SQL implementations of query operators except the Contains operator." It didn't  accept  "Any" operator

Comment: @halit check my new Edit, if you just replace your foreach statement with that it should work.